# Why do I get "use of undeclared type or module" error when calling a struct's function?

Tags: rust

I have the following code in Rust:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn get_value() -> &'static str;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct;

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn get_value() -> &'static str {
        "has value"
    }
}


fn main() {
    println!("My value: {}", MyStruct::get_value());
    has_trait(MyStruct);
}

fn has_trait<T>(trt: T) where T: MyTrait + std::fmt::Debug {
    println!("{:?}", trt)
}
```

This code is fine. It defines a trait and a struct. The struct implements the trait; which requires to implement a function. Everything is fine until now. But if I try the following code:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn get_value() -> &'static str;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct;

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn get_value() -> &'static str {
        "has value"
    }
}


fn main() {
    println!("My value: {}", MyStruct::get_value());
    has_trait(MyStruct);
}

fn has_trait<T>(trt: T) where T: MyTrait + std::fmt::Debug {
    println!("{:?}", trt::get_value())
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `trt`
  --> src/main.rs:21:22
   |
21 |     println!("{:?}", trt::get_value())
   |                      ^^^ use of undeclared type or module `trt`
```

Now, I don't really understand very well why that wouldn't work. `trt` should represent a copy of `myStruct` and then it should have its own functions, right?

Interestingly, this following code will compile:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn get_value(&self) -> &'static str;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct;

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn get_value(&self) -> &'static str {
        "has value"
    }
}


fn main() {
    println!("My value: {}", MyStruct.get_value());
    has_trait(MyStruct);
}

fn has_trait<T>(trt: T) where T: MyTrait + std::fmt::Debug {
    println!("{:?}", trt.get_value())
}
```

So what is exactly wrong with the code that doesn't compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I don't really understand very well why that wouldn't work. `trt` should represent a copy of `MyStruct` and then it should have its own functions, right?

It doesn't quite work that way for associated functions in Rust.
With the identifier `trt`, you can call *methods* where `trt` is the receiver (`self` or one of its variations such as `&self` or `&mut self`). However, `get_value()` does not have a receiver, so it is an *associated function*. This resembles a *static method* in some languages such as Java. Unlike Java, associated functions in Rust can only be called by specifying the type or type parameter with that function:

```rust
fn has_trait<T>(trt: T) where T: MyTrait + std::fmt::Debug {
    println!("{:?}", T::get_value())
}
```

This will now work, and would not even need the parameter `trt`, because we're just calling an associated function of the type `T`, rather than a method.
Although `trt` is an identifier to a function parameter in this context, the compiler will actually try to interpret it as something else (module name, type name, ...) once combined with the `::` token, hence the given error message.

Comment: Thanks. It works!. However, doesn't T represent the Trait. The trait doesn't implement the function. The struct does (which is passed through the function). Trying to display it, it says "expected value, found type parameter T". To be honest, my brain still doesn't understand it.

Comment: @OmarAbid Traits declare things, rather than implement themselves. `MyTrait` does in fact declare the associated function `get_value()`, which is why it can be called from a type `T` bound by that trait. That other error must have emerged from an attempt to use the type as a value.

Comment: I think it is starting to make some sense. T is myStruct. But isn't "trt" myStruct too? In that case, what is the difference between trt and T?

Comment: `T` is a type parameter of the function `has_trait`. When this function is called, this `T` is monomorphized to a concrete type, in this case `MyStruct`. `trt` is a value of type `T`, and so, will be a value of type `MyStruct` when `T` is `MyStruct`. One is a type, whereas the other one is an actual value. It might be worth revisiting [section 10.2 of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html), which contains a deeper explanation about traits and monomorphization.

Comment: @OmarAbid `MyStruct` is a **type**. `trt` is a **value** which happens to have type `MyStruct`. You can call a method on a *value* using the `.` operator. You can call an associated function on a *type* using the `::` operator. But you can't use the `.` operator on a *type* and you can't use the `::` operator on a *value*. The difference between values and types is very stark in Rust; it's a good thing to have a handle on.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks. I think I got it now.